# SSL Ajax type of certificate for the static domain (image + js)

Tags: iis, iis-7, ssl-certificate, https, certificate

I have a page that is SSL and has a valid certificate extended. (mainpage.com)
But this page request some static content to another domain(page-static.com), basicly images and js.

Actually i have only a certificate for my mainpage.com. So now when i request this page i get invalid ssl page because it contains invalid encrypted data (the one provided by the www.page-static.com)

What kind of certificate do i need for the www.page-static.com. Do i need the same one as the mainpage.com, because this certificate are expensive (it's a extended certificate). Or a cheap certificate from godaddy will do the trick. This is another question do both certificates have to be signed by the same root provider and/or the same encryption key length (or it can be only 128 bits)?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

By the sound of it you have a server that a client accesses with a valid security certificate, and some of the content loaded on to the page comes from a site that does not have an SSL certificate.

You will need to put the static content under an SSL protected page as well. This could be as simple as mirroring the content on your own server that has SSL already setup.

If this is not the case could you clarify your question?

Comment: You get it, i will clarify my question. My question is more specific on what kind of certificate do I need

Comment: Any regular web certificate will work to get rid of the unencrypted content warnings. A certificate from godaddy will work fine (though I have personal reservations about there business practices, that isn't what your asking for ;) )

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer,

Any ssl protocol do the trick. You only need one valid certificate as godaddy ones.

thanks.